# Add additional folders to Apple's TCC and PPPC permission system

Tags: macos, permission, folders

In the latest macOS versions one must explicitly grant folder access to `~/Desktop`, `~/Documents`, and `~/Downloads` in order for apps to access these locations.

How can I add custom folders to this permission system? E.g I want to create `/home/user/programming` which then only my IDEs can access. If I put it in `~/Documents` then my image editing program and word processor would have access to my programming files, which I do not want.

Comment: The permissions system will also give access to those folders if you are indicating your intention by navigating to files with an open panel.

Comment: Was also wondering about that. For example if I do 'right-click' + 'open with' it works perfectly fine. But I thought it then just grants permission to this one specific file.

Comment: Certain locations are deemed more sensitive, but by double-clicking, using the contextual menu, or navigating to a file with an app's open panel, you have indicated your intent to allow whatever application to access it, so they can do so without needing to ask.  Normally you only get the permissions dialog the first time something tries to access those locations without you providing that specific intent - when using scripting, for example.